# How to use a 4k byte sector external hard drive on Windows Xp

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I'm used to backing up data **from** my **Xp** computer **to** external **usb hard drives** every now & then. Recently I bought a new 3TB WD external hard drive but once I plugged it to the usb port, strangely enough it just appeared in the list of device manager (I can safely remove it from system tray) but **not** in the list of **Disk management** nor in the explorer!!
When I try it on a Windows 7 computer it worked effortlessly. I'm suspicious that it is the transition from 512 to 4k sector size. Is there a trick that would enable me to use the device in Xp too? Would it work out if I reformatted it using Windows 7 utility to any specific allocation unit size?

Please help, 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any large-sector disks, such as 4K native, 512E, or any non-512 native disks, are **not supported** on any Windows XP version.

However, WD quick format can fix this:

Please check the [WD official documentation](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=3868)

Just follow the guide and select Window XP compatibility when formatting the drive. It should then work.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you saved me, I was just too busy these days that I'd try your unbelievably creditable solution but finally I did & it worked like a charm. Now Xp explorer put up this brand new external hard drive as soon as it's plugged in :-)

Comment: Glad it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I disagree slightly with @Overmind. While Microsoft may not officially support large sectors on XP, that doesn't mean it won't work. I can successfully use a Seagate 8TB drive on Windows XP SP3 *because* it has 4K Native sectors. In other words, because it identifies as having 4K sectors, Windows XP is able to use it normally.

Based on your description, the issue I believe you're running into is that the drive is formatted with GPT. That would explain why it works on Windows 7 but not XP. If you want it to work on XP *and* be able to access the full 3 TB, then you need to verify the sector size in msinfo32. Just run msinfo32 and navigate to Components->Storage->Disks, then find your external drive in the list. If it says, "Bytes/Sector 4096" then it is XP-compatible and just needs to be reformatted with the WD Quick Formatter as Overmind suggested. If it says, "Bytes/Sector 512", then Windows XP will not be able to access more than the first ~2 TB or so.